# Can't create a remote interpreter with Docker-compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose, pycharm

Hello guys i need your help!

I can't configure the remote docker-compose interpreter in PyCharm, I keep getting the following error:

[image]

and the corresponding log entry:

> 2020-08-09 02:45:55,299 [6304130]   WARN -
> ckaging.InstalledPackagesPanel - The following command was executed:
>
> C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm 2020.1.3\bin\runnerw64.exe
> C:\Users\Angel\Downloads\docker-compose-Windows-x86_64.exe -f
> D:\Archiv\Projects\PycharmProjects\django_with_db\docker-compose.yml
> -f C:\Users\Angel\AppData\Local\JetBrains\PyCharm2020.2\tmp\docker-compose.override.241.yml
> run --rm --no-deps web
>
> The exit code: 1
>
> The error output of the command:
>
> Couldn't find `docker` binary. You might need to install Docker:
>
> https://docs.docker.com/engine/installation/windows/
>
> docker-compose finished with exit code 1

In my case, PyCharm is installed on Windows 10, and Docker and Docker-compose are on a separate server running CentOS and I use the following settings:

Docker:

[image]

Interpreter:

[image]

At the same time, Docker as a remote interpreter works fine, the problem only concerns the docker-compose.

I don't know if this matter or not, but I want to point out, that since Docker is not installed on a windows host, when I first tried to create a remote interpreter using docker-compose, PyCharm showed a message – can’t find the docker-compose executable. To overcome this, I downloaded the executable for my platform from the official Docker repository and manually specify the path to it:

[image]

Whether this is the right solution I don't know, but it's works

I am using the following software versions:

- Windows 10 build 19041
- PyCharm Professional 2020.2
- CentOS Linux release 8.2.2004
- Docker version 19.03.12, build 48a66213fe
- docker-compose version 1.26.2, build eefe0d31

Comment: That `DOCKER_HOST` setting is incredibly dangerous: if it works correctly, anyone who can reach your host at all can trivially root it, without needing any sort of login or password information.  I would not try to remote access via the Docker socket at all.  I would consider reinstalling the remote machine, if you're not extremely confident in your local network's security.  You should be able to install Python on the Windows host and just use that directly.

Comment: If I could install Docker on my host, that would solve all my problems, but unfortunately it is not possible, since enabling Hopper-V on Windows makes it impossible to use other types of virtualization. I used DOKER_HOST here in the hopes that it would help solve my problem, but it didn't help. I know about security concerns when using sockets, but at the moment it does not matter